# If an op-amp does not provide an enable input, how can I shut down (disable) the op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an [AD8397](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8397.pdf) which does not provide shut down or disable function pins.

I thought up a possible solution: disable the op-amp with the EN pin of the voltage regulator. I have added a regulator with an enable pin for this op-amp. Can I disable the op-amp by disabling the regulator? Are there any problems with disabling an op-amp this way?

### The goal

This circuit is 48 channels analog front-end with op-amp for fanout. Since sometimes some channels (op-amps) have no signal input, I'd like to disable some channels of op-amp for saving power. Our input signal of op-amp is a pulse about 100 ns width and +2V Vpp. Every channel (op-amp) is following an LDO for power.

[image]

Comment: It depends on what the op amp does. If there is an input voltage present, it may damage if you simply remove supply voltage.

Comment: I think you can just place diode between noninverting input (canthode) and ground (anode) or even can go without it. From what i saw you using single supply operation for opamp. If you will use diode use low voltage drop ones, since if somehow signal will be presented when you have no power on opamp, voltage on input channel will be limited by voltage drop of diode. You can see such "trick" in book Opamps for everyone.

Comment: You would have to disable the OPA355 too. You haven't shown power rails for any op-amps as far as I can tell and that is vital.

Comment: Sorry. The power rail is 0 to +4.5V

Comment: Oh, I can't explain clear. I hope OPA355 is always on. The LDO LP5907 for OPA355.

Comment: It might be ok if you use 50Ohm termination at input of OPA355, which is placed on schematic, but using LDO's enable pin is good idea

Comment: Hi @Alex: Many thanks your suggestion. I recommend you post above you said in the solution :)

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/improper-power-sequencing-in-op-amps-analyzing-the-risks.html you have to be sure that the opamp has a large input impedence .if IC start to heating up will burn

Comment: Hi electronx: OPA355 doesn't seem to be a problem because of the CMOS input stage. But I review AD8397 which input impendence is only 87k ohm @100kHz. I think maybe I have to add diode on the non-inverting input line to protect AD8397.

Comment: FYI on J1 you have CC1 and CC2 marked as no-connection.  You probably want to tie each of them to ground with a 5.1k resistor, so that you identify yourself as a USB-C power consuming device ("upstream facing port") and are given the 5V you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since when you want to shut down your op amp only when input signals are not present, you can disable supply voltage to op amp. For additional protection you can just place a diode between the non-inverting input (cathode) and ground (anode) or even can go without it. From what I saw you using single supply operation for the op amps. If you will use a diode use low voltage drop ones, since if somehow a signal (negative) will be presented when you have no power on an op amp, voltage on the input channel will be limited by the voltage drop of the diode. You can see such a "trick" in the book  "Op amps for Everyone". Using OPA355 always powered might be ok if you use 50 ohm termination at the input of the OPA355, which is placed on schematic, but using LDO's enable pin is good idea.

Comment: If the OPA355 is operational and 3 of the 4 AD8397 op-amps are required to be operational, the AD8397 that is to be disabled will receive a voltage input that may cause it problems if its supply rail is disabled. Disabling an LDO will, apparently (it seems) disable 2 AD8397 devices so, I don't see how this can work either. The devil will be in the detail on this particular job.

Comment: From showed chunk i can't say other devices, powered by this LDO. And i don't see specs of OPA355 which say it's behavior with single supply operation. And i assumed that it can go to low enough voltage so AD8397's will stay safe. OPA355 input is also terminated so high-frequency noises should be no problem for this node.

Comment: One LDO regulator powers two AD8397 op-amps so, unless @culywei can live with op-amps being shut-down in pairs, then using the LDO shutdown feature is a non-starter. Even if it is acceptable to curlywei, the disabled op-amps will load the input line and disturb the signal going to the two AD8397s that remain enabled. You need to think about this a bit more and not immediately respond with an answer until all bases are covered <-- that's my advice. I know he asked you to leave an answer but, you shouldn't do that until you are sure about things.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka: Yes I'll shutdown OPA with 8 channels(1 AD8397 with 2 OP-AMPs) as a unit(minimum). OK! Since turning off LDO as turning off OP-AMP, which has a risk, I think maybe I add *Analog Switch* likes [MAX312](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX312-MAX314.pdf) and 1:12 decoder for control MAX312 between OPA355 and AD8397 which would be a low risk solution.

Comment: @curlywei it's going to be tricky using analogue switches due to their capacitance to ground (47 pf per channel) <-- this can cause the OPA355 to become unstable and it can significantly distort the waveforms. Also, the "off" isolation at high frequencies is really poor (as is most analogue switches). Good luck with this not-so-low-risk solution!

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka mentioned! OK! The input capacitance of analog switch is very tricky like capacitance of photodiode. AFAIK, TIA of photodiode has feedback capacitance for 
compensating capacitance of photodiode. I'll consider this approach. Many thanks your suggestion. I learned a lot!